# Microsoft Access is creating and saving a new record into a table when I close forms (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 2 forms created, one is a main form that is used for data entry, the second is a pop up form that gets displayed when a certain choice is made, when the pop up form is called it has a list box with all the data that was similar to the name/address of the given details and fills in textboxes on the 2nd form with the details provided. Everything works as I was intending until I closed both forms and re-entered the same details, a new record that's based on the data given previous was added to the table and I'm not sure why

[Forms-Working-Intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm0Lr.png) || [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK8wY.png)

I tried diving into the code I wrote for these forms, I did have a subroutine that would input data from what was inputted into the fields but I noticed that it wasn't calling that subroutine at all since when it does it sets the the string fields to be capital & the Boolean field to be true in the table. here are the two relevant code blocks that I'm assuming there's an issue.

data entry form code:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

Dim custID As Integer
Dim CustomerRS As Recordset
Dim OfficeRS As Recordset

Dim CustomerCheckSQL As String
Dim CustomerCheckRS As Recordset

Set CustomerRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("CustomerDetails")
Set OfficeRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("OfficeDetails")

CustomerCheckSQL = "SELECT * FROM [CustomerDetails] WHERE [CustomerName] = '" & Me.CustomerName & "' AND [StreetName] = '" & Me.StreetName & "'"
Set CustomerCheckRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(CustomerCheckSQL)

If IsNull(Me.CustomerName) Or IsNull(Me.Unit) Or IsNull(Me.StreetName) Or IsNull(Me.City) Or IsNull(Me.Province) Or IsNull(Me.PostalCode) Or IsNull(Me.OfficeNumber) Or IsNull(Me.OperatorNumber) Or IsNull(Me.AdminFee) Then
    MsgBox "Please fill out all of the required fields"
Else
    If CustomerCheckRS.RecordCount >= 1 Then
        Dim answer As Integer
            answer = MsgBox("A Customer with that name and address already exist. did you want to replace(yes) or create a new record(no).", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Cust Tracking")
            If answer = vbYes Then
                DoCmd.OpenForm "test", , , , , acDialog, Me.CustomerName & ";" & Me.StreetName & ";" & Me.Unit & ";" & Me.City & ";" & Me.Province & ";" & Me.PostalCode
            Else
                insertCustomer CustomerRS, OfficeRS
            End If
    Else
        insertCustomer CustomerRS, OfficeRS
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

This one is for the pop up form

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim criterias As String
Dim arrCriterias() As String

criterias = Nz(Me.OpenArgs, "")

arrCriterias = Split(criterias, ";")

lsCustomerData.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM CustomerDetails WHERE [CustomerName] = '" & arrCriterias(0) & "' AND [StreetName] = '" & arrCriterias(1) & "'"
lsCustomerData.Requery

Me.CustomerName.Value = lsCustomerData.Column(1, 1)
Me.StreetName.Value = lsCustomerData.Column(3, 1)
Me.Unit.Value = arrCriterias(2)
Me.City.Value = arrCriterias(3)
Me.Province.Value = arrCriterias(4)
Me.PostalCode.Value = arrCriterias(5)
End Sub
```

I am not including the insertCustomer code as I know for certain that the issue lies elsewhere. If someone knows why exactly it's adding a new row to my table that would be a big help, I'm at a complete loss.

I'm using Microsoft Access version 2007-2016

Answer (score 0):

The `RecordCount` property of a RecordSet does not actually return the amount of records that are in a given RecordSet but instead returns the number of records that have been accessed. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-recordcount-property-dao for more detailed information)

You can solve this by calling the `MoveLast` method of the Recordset (and therefor accessing all records) before getting the `RecordCount`

Comment: I'm not really sure where exactly you want me to add/replace that or how that really solves my issue of a record being added.

Comment: @Jacob well there is one spot in your code that uses the `RecordCount` property - so maybe there? - It could lead to the If Else not triggering as expected / wanted, because even if a Recordset had 100 records you wouldn't know / the code wouldn't

Comment: I supposed I phrased my response wrong, I more so meant where you wanted me to add the MoveLast method as I cannot just replace recordCount with it in the logic as        "If CustomerCheckRS.MoveLast>= 1" wouldn't be correct syntax

Comment: @Jacob first do `CustomerCheckRS.MoveLast` and then in the next line you can have the If condition that checks the RecordCount. This way you'll have accessed all records before reading the RecordCount property (and therefor will get the correct/expected result)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my issue wasn't with my code or the 2nd form at all, the issue was that the main form was bound to the tables in my database so any changes into the text fields got saved automatically into the tables.